# Update behaving as upsert in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have following table structure in cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ks.job_status(
    job_uuid text,
    job_updated_status text,
    job_status_description text,
    PRIMARY KEY(job_uuid)
);
```

I am using below query to update a non-existent record in the table

```
update ks.job_status 
set job_updated_status='gerp', 
    job_status_description='hello' 
where job_uuid = 'abc'
```

I am expecting some error, as the record i am trying to update is not existing.
But as mention in the cqlsh docs the update is behaving as an **upsert** and it is creating a new record.

What should be my update query in order to update the data only if the record exist?

Comment: The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31101500/5761558) on that question shows how you can use `IF EXISTS` to prevent insertion when record does not exist.